# Fix Windows 8 EFI Boot on 32-Bit images

Tags: windows-8, boot, 64-bit, uefi

I've been trying to install Windows 8 on a UEFI-based computer using a USB flash drive. As far as I've have been able to gather, there have been some issues with this kind of installation, as the DVD images fail to boot in UEFI mode. Following this tutorial http://blog.thijssen.ch/2012/07/install-windows-8-in-uefi-mode.html, I've able to install from 64-bit only iso's, however I'd like to install from a AIO iso (only one available in my native language).

I've tried copying the bootx64.efi files from the /efi folder of a 64-bit image, but I get an error screen. Is there a way to fix/correct the iso image so that it can boot in UEFI mode?

Comment: You need to use a 64-bit installation of Windows if you want to use a UEFI BIOS.  Clearly trying to load a 64-bit .efi file won't work if your using a 32-bit operating system.

Comment: The iso is not 32-bit only, it has both 64 and 32 bits installations...

Answer (score 1):

32Bit Windows versions don't support UEFI. I think this causes your issues. You can export (`DISM /Export-Image`) the 64Bt Install.WIM from your AIO Install.wim and only use the correct one.

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for... and how would I do that?

Comment: 5s google: **Dism /Export-Image /SourceImageFile:install.wim /SourceIndex:1 /DestinationImageFile:install2.wim** Replace the index with the 64Bit Image you need.

Comment: It doesn't work, apparently export-image is not a valid option... and what do you mean by the replacing the index? I only have one install.wim in my AIO DVD.

Comment: this is correct, but a WIM can include several versions. The index specifies which version you want to use. Please learn a bit how this works, before asking such basic questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and boot Windows 8 32bit UEFI, but it's not that simple. It involves using command prompt and a Windows PE 32 bit UEFI boot disk (if available) along with a 32 bit Windows WIM file.

The most easy way is to remove the hard disk (or ssd) and get a USB adapter for it and use another workstation to deploy the image. If this option is not available you will need to boot from the Windows PE disk 32 bit UEFI and have the wim image in that disk.

I'll try to keep the instructions as simple as possible. If you don't understand a term, you can google that. There's plenty of information available. If you don't have a wim file available google instructions on how to capture an OS image properly. The beauty of this is that it doesn't have to be UEFI, it can be BIOS, but it has to be 32 bit. I installed mine to a Virtual Machine then captured the wim file.

On CMD type diskpart
Type "list disk" so you know what disk you are going to format, then follow the next commands:

---

Select disk #
Clean
Convert GPT
Create partition MSR size=128
Create Partition EFI size=100
Format fs=fat32 quick Label="System"
Assign letter=S
Create Partition Primary
Format fs=ntfs quick label="Windows"
Assign letter=W

### exit

Now it's time to apply the image using DISM

---

Dism /apply-image /imagefilae:(directory and filename of your wim file) index:#(the number of the image. If you used a captured image of your own, type 1, otherwise you'll need to know which one is it) /applydir:w:\

example:
dism /apply-image /imnagefile:x:\win832uefi.wim /index:1 /applydir:w:\

---

Wait until it finished. USB 2.0 can be quite slow.

Finally, this is the crucial part, adding the boot manager with UEFI support

---

w:\windows\system32\bcdboot w:\windows /f ALL /s S:

---

Voilá! Install the HDD to your device or reboot and remove Windows PE media. You should be able to boot uefi 32 bit now.

Hope this helped.